# How to determine the number of columns per row variably in a CSV File with Python?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing, export-to-csv

I am analyzing xml-structured Textfiles about insider dealings. I wrote some code to parse through the XML-structure and write my output in a CSV file. The results of the files are written per line and the analyzed information is written in individual columns. But in some files information is present in multiple times and my code override the information in the cells, in the end only one date is in the cell of my CSV-File.

```
import csv
import glob
import re
import string
import time
import bs4 as bs


# User defined directory for files to be parsed
TARGET_FILES = r'D:\files\'
# User defined file pointer to LM dictionary

# User defined output file
OUTPUT_FILE =  r'D:\ouput\Parser.csv'
# Setup output
OUTPUT_FIELDS = [r'Datei', 'transactionDate', r'transactionsCode', r'Director', r'Officer', r'Titel', r'10-% Eigner', r'sonstiges', r'SignatureDate']


def main():

    f_out = open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'w')
    wr = csv.writer(f_out, lineterminator='\n', delimiter=';')
    wr.writerow(OUTPUT_FIELDS)

    file_list = glob.glob(TARGET_FILES)
    for file in file_list:
        print(file)
        with open(file, 'r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as f_in:
            soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(f_in, 'xml')

        output_data = get_data(soup)
        output_data[0] = file                       
        wr.writerow(output_data)


def get_data(soup):

# overrides the transactionDate if more than one transactions disclosed on the current form
# the number determine the column for the output


    _odata = [0] * 9

    try:
        for item in soup.find_all('transactionDate'):
            _odata[1] = item.find('value').text               
    except AttributeError:
        _odata[1] = ('keine Angabe')
    try:
        for item in soup.find_all('transactionAcquiredDisposedCode'):
            _odata[2] = item.find('value').text
    except AttributeError:
        _odata[2] = 'ka'
    for item in soup.find_all('reportingOwnerRelationship'):
        try:
            _odata[3] = item.find('isDirector').text
        except AttributeError:
            _odata[3] = ('ka')
        try:
            _odata[4] = item.find('isOfficer').text
        except AttributeError:
            _odata[4] = ('ka')
        try:
            _odata[5] = item.find('officerTitle').text
        except AttributeError:
            _odata[5] = 'ka'
        try:
            _odata[6] = item.find('isTenPercentOwner').text
        except AttributeError:
            _odata[6] = ('ka')
        try:
            _odata[7] = item.find('isOther').text
        except AttributeError:
            _odata[7] = ('ka')
        try:
            for item in soup.find_all('ownerSignature'):
                _odata[8] = item.find('signatureDate').text
        except AttributeError:
            _odata[8] = ('ka')

    return _odata


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('\n' + time.strftime('%c') + '\nGeneric_Parser.py\n')
    main()
    print('\n' + time.strftime('%c') + '\nNormal termination.')
```

Actually the code works, but overwrites columns if, for e.g. more than one transacion date is given in the file. So I need a code that automatically uses the next column for each transaction date. How could this work?
I would be glad if someone have a solution for my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are iterating over the result of 
`soup.find_all()`
and every time you are writing to the same value.  You need to do something with
`_odata` in each iteration, otherwise you will only end up with whatever is written to it the last time.

If you can show us what the data you're trying to parse actually looks like, perhaps we could give a more specific answer.

Comment: here you can find the link to a sample document: (I cut the first lines with another code so my file starts at <?xml version="1.0"?>
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1704964/0000899243-19-003763.txt